# Try-Catch not catching custom exception type

Tags: php, syntax, try-catch

This is a pretty simple question, and it's blatantly my own newb status that's holding me back. Apologies.

Why isn't this bit of code working?

```
    try
    {
        create_account($accountXML);
        echo "<p>Successfully created your account.</p>";
        try
        {
            create_page($pageXML,$base64_credentials);
            echo "<p>Successfully created your page!</p>";
        }
        catch (exception $e){ echo "<p>$e</p>"; }
    }
    catch(exception $e)
    {
        echo "<p>$e</p>";           
    }
    catch(emailInUseException $e)
    {
        echo "<p>Error: Email already in use. Could not create account.</p>";
    }
```

Within the `create_account` function...

```
if ((!substr_count($response, "200 Account created successfully") > 0)) // If failed
{
    if ((substr_count($response, "400 EmailAddressInUse") > 0)) // If email address already in use
        {
            throw new emailInUseException($response);
        }
        throw new exception("Error: Could not create account. Reason: $response");
}
```

The `emailInUse` catch doesn't seem to be working :(

**Update:** With debugging enabled I get the following error: `Fatal error: Class 'emailInUseException' not found`

I'm sure it's something really awfully obvious. Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is in the `emailInUse` function?

Comment: @Neal: `emailInUse` appears to be a custom exception type. Probably better named `EmailInUseException` but who am I to judge?

Comment: @Django: Good call. While it does come down to personal preference, it's fairly standard to name exception types with "Exception" in them for clarity. It's a good convention to follow especially if other developers will be working on the project at some point. Also, a week after you write the code, *you* will quickly discover that you've become the "other" developer.

Comment: @Agent Yes, it makes perfect sense to do that. I can imagine that, like you say, I will be that "other" developer before I know it!

Comment: Be sure that you include|require the needed php file which has the exception class you try to call in your function.
Be sure you write the class name well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    catch(emailInUse $e)
    {
        echo "<p>Error: Email already in use. Could not create account.</p>";
    }
    catch(exception $e)
    {
        echo "<p>$e</p>";           
    }
```

You need to change the order. The more general exceptions need to come to the bottom, otherwise your code will simply catch it and throw it before the specific exception is caught.

Comment: Hmm, Check the type of exception that is being caught in your general catch. See if it actually matches your class type. Is it being caught at all?

Comment: @Django: Just to echo what JohnP said.. your `create_account` function throws *both* types of exception, so make sure you're actually catching an `emailInUse` rather than a plain `exception` type.

Comment: No. I checked. I put some text in `exception` and it's not being shown. Also, I put an `echo` after the `try` and it's not being shown either. It's basically stopping somewhere in `create_account`. Hmm :(

Comment: @Django Well, you could try debugging it. I recommend installing xdebug and debugging your app. This link is for xdebug + eclipse : http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803-Introducing-xdebug

Comment: Ah, yes! I've gotten used to debugging in ASP.Net, and it's a nightmare in PHP :( I'm loathe to spend more money on an IDE, though. I already have Visual Studio 2010, Dreamweaver (awful!) and PHP Designer. I'll look into proper debugging software. Thanks!

Comment: @Django Just so you know, eclipse PDT and xdebug are both free :) I use PDT and it's great. Takes about 5 mins to setup xdebug to use with eclpse. I kid you not!

Comment: That's what I like to hear! I'll get onto that now. Thanks!

Comment: I finally got debugging set up and this is the error I received: `Fatal error: Class 'emailInUseException' not found`

Comment: I don't know if class names are case-sensitive or not (as variable names are but function names are not). Anyway, the first letter of a class in lowercase makes baby jesus cry. Also, take care that linux filesystem is case-sensitive, so emailInUseException.php is a different file than EmailInUseException.php

Comment: @Carlos Campderrós class names aren't case sensitive. @Django Reinhardt you'll need to go through your include code to see whether your exception class is getting properly included or not. Make sure your class is actually extending an exception

Comment: Having the same problem, as here is no solution, I searched in php dot net and found this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php So, when implemented the methods listed, problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

Catch all exceptions

```
try{

}catch(Throweable $exception)
{

}
```